# netCDF raster layers not loading in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, netcdf

I have worked with netCDF files in QGIS before, but since I installed QGIS 3.6 they won't load ("myfile.nc" is not an admitted raster data source), nor do they load in QGIS 2.18 anymore. I find this particularly strange. I am working under Windows 10. It appears both versions of QGIS are using GDAL 2.2.4. I don't know if that is the problem but when I run gdalinfo --formats on the OSGeo4W Shell, netCDF does show up:

netCDF -raster,vector- (rw+s): Network Common Data Format

I was looking for a way to downgrade GDAL in case this was the problem but did not find anything feasible at my level. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Can you post some more metadata about your NetCDF dataset, such as an `ncdump -h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS 3.6 NetCDF are loaded differently if they have a single variable or multiple. With one variable it work as before in QGIS 2.8. With more than one variables, then 3/2 dimensions need to have the names X,Y,Time or longitude, latitude and Time. GDAL gives a warning for this but in QGIS it seems mandatory.